# Android - Service and 2 activities: IncomingHandler not fired for one of them

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I have an application with a TabActivity and one tab inside called LiveActivity. The application also has a service that regularly updates the GPS coordinates of the handset and some other information. Here is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="fr.eyquem.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity
            android:name=".TabActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".LiveActivity"></activity>
        <service android:name=".SensorService"></service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My service is supposed to send updates to all registered activities every time there is an update of the GPS coordinates. To test it, I first implemented the communication between the service and the TabActivity, by changing the application title when TabActivity receives the message. This works well.

Step 1. The service sends a message through the following method:

```
private void sendMsgToUI(int what, String[] values) {
    Log.i("SensorService->sendMsgToUI()", " YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY ");
    for (int i=mClients.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
        Log.i("SensorService->sendMsgToUI()", " ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ ");
        try {
            String key="";
            switch(what){
                case MSG_COORDINATES:
                    key="Coordinates";
                    break;
                default:
                    key="";
            }

            Log.i("SensorService->sendMsgToUI()", String.valueOf(what) +" "+key);

            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putStringArray(key, values);
            Message msg = Message.obtain(null, what);
            msg.setData(b);
            mClients.get(i).send(msg);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // The client is dead. Remove it from the list; we are going through the list from back to front so this is safe to do inside the loop.
            mClients.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Step 2. The Activity receives the message through:

```
class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        String[] values;

        Log.i("TabActivity->IncomingHandler()", String.valueOf(msg.what));

        switch (msg.what) {
            case SensorService.MSG_COORDINATES:
                values = msg.getData().getStringArray("Coordinates");
                setTitle("MobScanR: " + values[0]);
                break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

This works well for TabActivity but not for the LiveActivity. It actually seems that the LiveActivity is not registered by the service (i put a lot of log messages and see for instance only one time the "ZZZZZZZ" log while there should be 2), although I checked that the method is called properly:

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        Log.i("LiveActivity->onServiceConnected()", " AAAAAAAA " + service.toString());
        mService = new Messenger(service);
        //textStatus.setText("Attached.");
        try {
            Message msg = Message.obtain(null, SensorService.MSG_REGISTER_CLIENT2);
            msg.replyTo = mMessenger;
            mService.send(msg);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.e("LiveActivity->onServiceConnected()", " HHHHHHHHH ERROR " + service.toString(), e);
            // In this case the service has crashed before we could even do anything with it
        }
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        // This is called when the connection with the service has been unexpectedly disconnected - process crashed.
        mService = null;
        //textStatus.setText("Disconnected.");
        Log.i("LiveActivity->onServiceDisconnected()", "Service Disconnected");
    }
};
```

I dont want to post the whole code there as I don't ask for extensive debugging, but anyone has an idea about where to look and what could explain this different behavior between 2 activities and the service?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have tried to copy exactly the code of the TabActivity that works to create a new tab I called RealtimeActivity, i changed the minimum amount of lines to make it a tab of the TabView and adjusted the code of the service. Same problem, it looks like the connection to the service from RealtimeActivity does not go through.